# Control multiple slicers with a single prompt using vba

Tags: vba, date, excel

I currently have a spreadsheet that has about 40 columns of data, 16 of which are dates.  I was tasked to add some sort of function that would allow an easier ability to filter through dates and date ranges.

What I did was I transformed the spreadsheet into an xml table and then added slicers to each of the columns that utilized dates. I added a macro button to help clear selections as well.

However I was told I didn't quite hit the mark as they want the function to filter all of the date columns from one central function (instead of various slicers)

Ideally what they want is a place to input two dates (start and end) and have the entire file filter to where those dates are true.

Supposedly they have utilized a spreadsheet that did exactly this using vba macros,  but I have no idea how to even start controlling the slicers.

I did create a vba code that auto filtered from a given date range,  but I can't get it to work with multiple filters (and I have to convert my xml table back to range)

```
Public Sub allFilter()

    Dim lngStart As Long, lngEnd As Long

    lngStart = Range("B1").Value 'assume this is the start date

    lngEnd = Range("B2").Value 'assume this is the end date

    Range("M5:M900").AutoFilter field:=1, _

        Criteria1:=">=" & lngStart, _

        Operator:=xlAnd, _

        Criteria2:="<=" & lngEnd

End Sub
```

Again,  ideally they want to be able to input the date range and have all filters respond to that input,  but I figure I've already created all the slicers and it may be easier to tell all slicers to filter the same way.

Sorry if this is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

i have something like:
    dim PT as pivottable
    Dim Sdate As SlicerCache
    Dim DateSlicer As Slicer

```
Set PT = Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Sdate = MyWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add(PT, "Dates")'"Dates" is the header of the column
Set DateSlicer = Sdate.Slicers.Add(SlicerDestination:=Sheets("Pivot"), Name:="Time period", Caption:="Dte", Top:=40 + 187.5 + 187.5, Left:=width_counter, Width:=144, Height:=187.5) 'Top Left WIDTH HEIGHT

'Loop a slicer
For Each sI In Sdate.SlicerItems

    Debug.Print "Caption; – > " & sI.Caption
    Debug.Print "Value; – > " + CStr(sI.Value)
    Debug.Print "Unique; Name; – > " + sI.Name
    Debug.Print "——————————————————————————"
    hoy = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    If CDate(sI.Value) < CDate(hoy) Then
    sI.Selected = False
    End If



Next
```

that way you filter the dates to leave the ones after today for example

Comment: Hi, it didn't work for me,  it gets stuck when setting the Pivot Table.  Is the Pivot table necessary?

Comment: i was assuming you had one, if not, use something like:

    Set PRange = Range("Table_D") '
    Set MyWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
  
    MyWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Sheets("Pivot").Range("A1"), TableName:="PivotTable1" _
 , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

i think slicers come with the pivot table. it would be better if you had one.